# Бот дублирует свои ответы по callback нажатиям на inline клавиатуру много раз

Tags: php, telegram-bot, telegram

Пишу телеграм бота "Тесты" на telegram-bot-sdk. На данный момент сделан выбор теста из базы.

Проблема: бот постоянно дублирует свои ответы. Которые в обработчике callback-ов. Посмотрите пожалуйста код, что у меня не так?

Дублируются сообщения внутри обработки callback, внутри swich. Их вывожу в чат:

```
$chat = $result['callback_query']['message']['chat']['id'];
```

Сообщение приветствия для `/start` выводится один раз. Его вывожу в чат:

```
$chat_id = $result["message"]["chat"]["id"];
```

Может в этом дело? Пробовала заменить внутри `swich $chat` на `$chat_id`, но она пустая внутри swich, т.к. сообщения не было, была нажата инлайн кнопка. Но в любом случае, $chat и $chat_id равны, поэтому может дело и не в этом. Прошу, скажите свое мнение.

```html
<?php   
include ('vendor/autoload.php');
include ('class/select.php');

use Telegram\Bot\Api; 
use Telegram\Bot\Keyboard\Keyboard;
use Telegram\Bot\Actions;
use Telegram\Bot\Commands\Command;
use Telegram\Bot\Objects\CallbackQuery;

$telegram = new Api ('ххх');

$result = $telegram -> getWebhookUpdates(); //Передаем в переменную $result полную информацию о сообщении пользователя

$text       = $result["message"]["text"];
$chat_id    = $result["message"]["chat"]["id"];
$name       = $result["message"]["from"]["username"];
$first_name = $result["message"]["from"]["first_name"];
$user_id    = $result["message"]["from"]["id"];
$contact    = $result['message']['contact'];


    //$keyboard = Keyboard::hide();
    $keyboard = Keyboard::make()
    ->inline()
    ->row(
        Keyboard::inlineButton(['text' => 'Выбрать тест', 'callback_data' => '/test_select']),
        Keyboard::inlineButton(['text' => 'Мои результаты', 'callback_data' => '/results'])        
    );

    if ($result->isType('callback_query')) {
        $data = $result['callback_query']['data'];
        $chat = $result['callback_query']['message']['chat']['id'];
        $chat_id = $result["message"]["chat"]["id"];
        switch ($data) {
            case '/test_select':
                $keyboard_test_select = Keyboard::make()
                    ->inline();
                $test_list = Select::getTestListDB();
                foreach($test_list as $key=>$val){
                    $keyboard_test_select->row(Keyboard::inlineButton($val));
                }
                $telegram->sendMessage([
                    'chat_id' => $chat,
                    'text' => 'Выберите тест:', 
                    'reply_markup' => $keyboard_test_select
                ]);
                break;
            case '/results':
                $telegram->sendMessage([
                    'chat_id' => $chat,
                    'text' => 'Информация пока в разработке.', 
                ]);
                break;                

            default:
                //Обработка выбора ТЕСТА
                $test_list = Select::getTestListDB();
                foreach($test_list as $key=>$val){
                    if($data==$val['callback_data'])
                    $telegram->sendMessage([
                            'chat_id' => $chat, 
                            'text' => 'Выбран тест: '.$val['text'], 
                            //'reply_markup' => $keyboard
                            ]
                    #code ...
                    );
                }
                break;
        }   
    
    }

    $hellotext = 'Приветствую, ';
    $hellotext .= ($first_name<>'') ? ($first_name.'!') : ($username.'!');
    $hellotext .= ' Тесты для сотрудников. Стартовая страница. Выберите дальнейшие действия:';
    
    $telegram->sendMessage([
        'chat_id' => $chat_id,
        'text' => $hellotext,
        'reply_markup' => $keyboard
    ]);


?>
```

P.S. Это мой первый бот. Если видите явные косяки в логике, прошу тоже сказать.

Answer (score 1):

Когда используете sendMessage с инлайн клавиатурой и кнопками (с типом CallbackQuery), после обработки клика на эти самые кнопки необходимо вызывать answerCallbackQuery, тем самым уведомим телеграм, что вы ответили на вызов по кнопке.

> После того, как пользователь нажмет кнопку обратного вызова, клиенты
> Telegram будут отображать индикатор выполнения, пока вы не вызовете
> answerCallbackQuery . Следовательно, необходимо отреагировать вызовом
> answerCallbackQuery, даже если уведомление для пользователя не
> требуется (например, без указания каких-либо дополнительных
> параметров).

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#callbackquery